# SQL: Pivoting two values into 1 column

Tags: sql, oracle

```
for fluid in ('CN' as liq, 'G' as  gas,'W' as  water)
```

What I would essentially like to do is make something that says

```
for fluid in ('CN' **or 'O'** as liq, 'G' as  gas,'W' as  water)
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and some explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.  Your question makes little sense, other than saying the `or` seems like a useful operator for this purpose.

Comment: This isn't how SQL works. You need to express your requirements as rules.

Comment: There are different fluid types designated by a letter in the "fluid" column. I am trying to pivot them out into multiple columns for each fluid type and summing them up based on values in another field. The first code sample works as intended, but I would like liquid can be CN or O, so I want to include them both. 'OR' cannot be used in this syntax, but I figured that would explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You really need to give a sample or describe your question better.  You can use case statements (case when fluid in ('CN','o' then liquid) to translate this, but the way you've stated this makes no sense in a sql context.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this with the PIVOT operator in Oracle. So you need an indirect way.

One possibility - especially if you need some prior processing (for example, because the table you are pivoting has too many columns, and you need to select a subset of columns first anyway, before pivoting) is to use a `case` expression in that subquery. For example:

```
select job, ten_twenty, all_others
from   (
         select sal, job, 
                case when deptno in (10, 20) then 10 else 30 end as dept_grp
         from   scott.emp
       )
pivot  ( sum(sal) for dept_grp in (10 as ten_twenty, 30 as all_others) )
;

JOB       TEN_TWENTY ALL_OTHERS
--------- ---------- ----------
CLERK           3200        950
SALESMAN                   5600
PRESIDENT       5000           
MANAGER         5425       2850
ANALYST         6000
```

Alternatively, you can do the pivoting first and apply one more operation in the outer `SELECT`. Here you need to be careful, because functions like `GREATEST` and simple addition ( `+` ) return `null` if even a single member is `null`, so you will need to use `coalesce` or `nvl` and such; and for some functions this won't work at all (`avg` in particular - `avg` of the averages of two subsets is generally not the average of the entire set, if the two subsets have different cardinality). Given all these shortcomings, I will choose to not even give an example - but the possibility does exist.